# Why Latest version of jquery is not seeing/used by my code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working with page myPAge.aspx that uses content.master which uses main.amster.
In the  section of main.master following is specified:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

In the myPage.aspx
there is

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageBottom" runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function myFunction() {                    
        var jq = $.fn.jquery;    // WHY this returns "1.3.2" as version of JQuery???
}
```

And it looks like actually 1.3.2 version is used, because I am not able to use .done in ajax callback.
Thank you

Comment: Can you post the part of the code that loads jQuery?

Comment: Look at the network traffic. You'll notice that something, somewhere, pulls in the old jQuery library and that there is no pull/override for a newer version. Version 1.3.2 sounds suspiciously like a version bundled with ASP-AJAX.

Comment: I did post code that loads, not sure why it's not here. Here it is again: In the <head> section of main.master following is specified:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>       
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

In the myPage.aspx
there is 
    <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageBottom" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: So, if it's ASP.AJAX, then what to do?

Comment: Wow. i see three different versions of jQuery in your code... So much extra code being included...

Comment: What is the point of loading this many jQuery libraries? Simply replace the main view one with jQuery 1.10 and then include jQuery Migrate to handle any old code that requires deprecated / removed functions.

Comment: I'd suggest not including 1.10 until you can get it down to only including 1 version. Replace `.done()` with `.success()` and move on. this is one of very few cases where i would suggest using a deprecated method. Better yet, don't use `.success`, instead pass the callback into the `success: function(){}` option.

Comment: 1.4.2 and 1.8.5 were included before I started to work with this code. I am trying to make work .done, I need it to wait for result returned from code-behind function, so can no t remove that. But I get Error: Object doesn't support this property or method. I think it may be because used JQuery version is 1.3.2 looks like. So, how to Override 1.3.2 with newer version? Thank you

Comment: .success will also *"wait for result returned from code-behind function"* I was referring to 1.4.2, 1.3.2, and 1.10.2. 1.8.5 is jQuery UI and not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Can I pass code-behind function as callback into the success: function(){} ?

Comment: Yes, you can. that is it's purpose. for all practical purposes, it acts exactly like the `.done` method.

Comment: success does Not wait until code-behind function done processing. ajax callback is asynchronous.

Comment: How to modify below code to use success to call testMethod() in code-behind?  $.ajax({ url: 'myPage.aspx/testMethod',
                type: "POST",                
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'name':'" + aNb + "'}",
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function () { alert("ok"); }).fail(function () { alert("not ok"); });